# Multiple separated graphs on Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am facing a simple problem I can't figure out: I am trying to plot multiple graphs with Matplotlib, but in separated graphs. This is an example code with random numbers:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.random.normal(10, 1, 100)
x2 = np.random.uniform(8, 12, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.sort(x1), label = 'Normal') 
ax.plot(np.sort(x2), label = 'Uniform')

plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

In this way I get 1 graph with 2 lines (the ax objects). I know that I can use Subplot to get 2 graphs next to each other, but what I want is to plot two different graphs, 1 for each variable, with 1 line each, all at once without starting a new code a initializing a new graph from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Without using subplots, I think one (quite ugly) way to do this is

```
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 1, 100) 
x2 = np.random.uniform(8, 12, 100)

data = [x1, x2]
label_list = ['Normal', 'Uniform']
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(np.sort(x), label = label_list[i])

    plt.legend() 
    plt.show()
```